# BFH Datepicker, change first day of week

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm trying with this with no results: bootstrap-formhelpers-datepicker.es_ES.js

```
var BFHMonthsList = [
  'Enero',
  'Febrero',
  'Marzo',
  'Abril',
  'Mayo',
  'Junio',
  'Julio',
  'Agosto',
  'Septiembre',
  'Octubre',
  'Noviembre',
  'Diciembre'
];

var BFHDaysList = [
  'DOM',
  'LUN',
  'MAR',
  'MIE',
  'JUE',
  'VIE',
  'SAB'
];

var BFHDayOfWeekStart = 1;
```

With:

```
    $(window).on('load', function () {
            $('div.bfh-datepicker').each(function () {
              var $datepicker = $(this);
                    $datepicker.bfhdatepicker($datepicker.data()).on('change.bfhdatepicker', function () {
                    var input = $(this).find("input");
                    if ( input.attr("name") == "fecha_inicio" ) {
                        $('[name=fecha_fin]').val( input.val() );
                        $(this).closest('div').click();
                    }   
              });
            })
          })
```

But sunday it stills the first day,

Also tried, with this:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('div.bfh-datepicker').each(function () {
      var $datepicker = $(this);
      console.log($datepicker.data());
            var theData = $datepicker.data();
            theData.firstDay = 6;
            console.log(theData);
      $datepicker.bfhdatepicker(theData).on('change.bfhdatepicker', function () {
            var input = $(this).find("input");
            if ( input.attr("name") == "fecha_inicio" ) {
                $('[name=fecha_fin]').val( input.val() );
                $(this).closest('div').click();
            }   
      });
    })
  })
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

-edit-

```
<script src="<?= base_url('administrator/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-datepicker.es_ES.js?v') ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?= base_url('administrator/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-datepicker.js') ?>"></script>
```

And this is the end of bfh-datepicker.js

```
/* APPLY TO STANDARD DATEPICKER ELEMENTS
   * =================================== */

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('div.bfh-datepicker').each(function () {
      var $datepicker = $(this);
      console.log($datepicker.data());
            var theData = $datepicker.data();
            theData.firstDay = 6;
            console.log(theData);
      $datepicker.bfhdatepicker(theData).on('change.bfhdatepicker', function () {
            var input = $(this).find("input");
            if ( input.attr("name") == "fecha_inicio" ) {
                $('[name=fecha_fin]').val( input.val() );
                $(this).closest('div').click();
            }   
      });
    })
  })

  $(function () {
    $('html')
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api', clearMenus)
    $('body')
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', toggle, BFHDatePicker.prototype.toggle)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar .month > .previous', BFHDatePicker.prototype.previousMonth)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar .month > .next', BFHDatePicker.prototype.nextMonth)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar .year > .previous', BFHDatePicker.prototype.previousYear)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar .year > .next', BFHDatePicker.prototype.nextYear)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar td:not(.off)', BFHDatePicker.prototype.select)
      .on('click.bfhdatepicker.data-api touchstart.bfhdatepicker.data-api', '.bfh-datepicker-calendar > table.calendar', function() { return false })
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

Edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjreexe0/1/) reproducing it

Comment: Can you show the code on how you include the scripts and where you set the `BFHDayOfWeekStart`. It should work, but it must be set before the plugin initializes (*because it only initializes once*)

Comment: Do you mean the html tag? updated question

Comment: Seems to work fine at http://jsfiddle.net/q41gbw6o/ (*whatever you set to `BFHDayOfWeekStart` works correct*). Can you post a link to your page ?

Comment: Not to the page.. but i reproduced it exactly how it's in my site: http://jsfiddle.net/sjreexe0/1/

Comment: What version of the helpers are you using ? The plugin file is completely different from the one on github (*the latest version*)

Comment: Im not sure, someone else did it. And its uncommented..